# CSS How to keep bodies of html file and included files from merging?

Tags: php, html, css

From what my trial and error has shown me is that when I (using php) include another php file, the bodies basically merge. 
 I have a CSS file that effects the main files body with a class of "main". The CSS file also effects the included files body with a class of "nav". 
 It appears that both the bodies of each file are effected by both of the styling that targets each class (even though the classes on each of the body tags are different). 
 
Am I mistaken? If not, is there a way I can get around this problem? Thanks!

Included nav file (which includes the css file (I only show the code relating to the body):

```
<body class="nav">
<ul class="navbar">
<li>
    <form action="login.php" method="post">
        <input id="email" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email">
        <input id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
        <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>
</li>
```

Main index file that includes the nav file :

```
<body class='index'>

<div class="block-signUp">
    <h1>Sign Up</h1>

    <form action="" method="post">
        <input class="firstname" type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name"
               value="<?php echo($_POST['firstname']) ?>">
        <input class="lastname" type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name"
               value="<?php echo($_POST['lastname']) ?>"> <br>
        <input class="email" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email"
               value="<?php echo($_POST['email']) ?>"><br>
        <input class="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"
               value="<?php echo($_POST['password']) ?>"><br>

        <div class="error-message hidden"></div>
        <input type="submit" value="Sign Up"><br>

    </form>
    <div><a href="login.php">Already Have An Account?</a></div>
</div>

</body>
```

The only CSS File in the whole website, which the nav file contains :

```
body.nav { /* This code effects the body in the index file as well for some reason */
        margin-top: 150px; /* Make nav bar at top of screen */
}
```

Comment: Really not sure what you mean by *"when I include another php file, the bodies basically merge"*. When you use `include` or `require`, you basically inject the script of one PHP file into the other at the point of execution. Any `<?php ... ?>` script is incorporated and any output is buffered.

Comment: Probably best to include your css files, as you might have included something in both instances.

Comment: @Phil I explained what happens above. The css for each body effects the other one for some reason. Even though I target the body with it's unique class in each file.

Comment: I only include the css file in the file that is being included.

Comment: For example, settings margin-top on the nav body also sets the margin for the other files body tag.

Comment: Can you post a sample code?

Comment: a (valid) html page can't have multiple `<body>` tags

Comment: @nogad So I guess that since I include it in php, it combines them into 1 html document, which therefore can't have two bodies? So that makes it cause this problem? I will post code

Comment: @user3771102 Code posted.

Comment: Have you tried `.nav` only in css?

Comment: May I also ask why do you have 2 `<body>` tags?

Comment: @user3771102 Still effects both files only targeting the .nav.

Comment: @user3771102 Those are separate files, each with 1 body tag.

Comment: Instead of `<body class="nav">` try making it div instead. Because you can only have 1 body tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

incorrect. First of, `include` and `require` is injection a script from one file to `__FILE__`(Master file, the file opened in .htaccess/URL) for example:

file1.php

```
<?php
    $first_script_var = true;
    include 'file2.php';
?>
```

file2.php

```
<?php
    if(isset($first_script_var) && $first_script_var === true){
        echo 'True';
    }
?>
```

Now file1.php would look like this:

```
<?php
    $first_script_var = true;
    include 'file2.php';
?>
<?php
    if(isset($first_script_var) && $first_script_var === true){
        echo 'True';
    }
?>
But if you would be using AJAX requests to the HTML DOM Element you would be requesting a file to the `html` tag it would load in the body tags.
```

Example: 
<
file1.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello world</title>
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
            });
            function load(){
                $("html").load("file2.php?string=" + document.getElementById("str").value); // $("html") is a selected, it basicly means we have selected the html tag. and the .load(); is a function from JQuery.
            }
        </script>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="str" placeholder="Echo 'text'" />
            <br />
            <input type="button" onclick="load();" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

file2.php

```
<head>
    <title>New title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        if(isset($_GET['string'])){ echo $_GET['string']; }
    ?>
</body>
```

this will result in replacing old header and old body tag with new head and new body tag, remember! Old javascript functions will still be remembered.

Answer (score 1):

If you have CSS declared in both include files and the styles are not scoped specifically to the elements on that page they you can get conflicts. This can especially happen if you are styling base tags like body, span, div, table, etc.

When the page is compiled in the browser everything gets thrown together. Long story short. Depending on order the CSS falls in the code it may get overwritten. Also depending on the specificity (real word) of the style it again may get overwritten.

This may help with that.

[CSS Specificity Calculator](https://specificity.keegan.st/)

Be sure that your main and nav class are not on both or especially being styled on both pages

Another thing I see some people do that are new to MVC (model view controller) and calling partial pages is that they include the HTML and BODY tags in the page that is being called in when it's not needed.

Comment: I only have 1 css file that is included in the nav. Then all of the pages in my site include that nav file, which contains the css.

Comment: After looking at the webpage in google chrome inpsection, I see that the body merges and it's class becomes equal to nav. That is what is happening. So I need to find a solution to this problem :\

Comment: It is probably best to have your CSS in an external file of its own. You can then link the one big CSS file in your main HTML/PHP file or link the CSS that specifically affect the nav in that HTML/PHP file. Either way you need to figure out how you want to scope your CSS.